# How many $g \in S_6$ are there such that $gxg^{-1} =x?$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, cyclic-decomposition

If $x = (123)(456)$ and $y = (234)(561)$, count the number of $g \in S_6$ such that

$1. gxg^{-1}=x$; and

$2. gxg^{-1}=y$

For 1, I got that $g = e_{S_6}$ (the identity in $S_6$) is one of them, and for 2, I got that $g = (123456)$ is an answer, but I have no idea how to "count" the number of $g$ in each.

Comment: How about $(123)$?

Comment: Yes, that works too. But my question is more geared towards how to "count" all the $g$'s that satisfy the quesiton.

Comment: What theorems are you familiar with? In particular, have you seen the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor No I am not familiar with that theorem.

Comment: Hint: The answers for part $1$ and part $2$ are equal.  For part $1$, the elements $g$ that work form a subgroup isomorphic to $Z_2\times Z_3^2$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Does it have something to do with the fact that both $x$ and $y$ are of conjugacy class $3+3$ so there are $3^2 * 2=18$ ways to arrange them thus there are $18 g$'s for each (this is just a guess)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but for a group $G$, the set of $g\in G$ such that $gxg^{-1}=x$ is a subgroup of $G$, called the stabilizer of $x\in G$.  If $S$ is the stabilizer of $x$, and $y\in G$ is such that there exists $h\in G$ for which $y=hgh^{-1}$, then the set of $g\in G$ such that $gxg^{-1}=y$ is given by $hS$.  Thus, if $S$ is finite, then $|S|=|hS|$.  Therefore, the number of solutions $g$ to $gxg^{-1}=x$ is the same as the number of solutions $g$ to $gxg^{-1}=y$, provided that $y$ is in the conjugacy class of $x$.